# Getting all running process with NtQuerySystemInformation (), returns all but current process

Tags: windows, winapi

My code is using the undocumented `winnt` function `NtQuerySystemInformation()` to get all running process. Though is not officially documented, there's plenty of 3'rd party docs out there (http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/UserMode/Undocumented%20Functions/System%20Information/NtQuerySystemInformation.html and http://www.exploit-monday.com/2013/06/undocumented-ntquerysysteminformation.html to begin with). the function is loaded dynamically (using `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()` ) but for convenient i'll write the call as if it was directly to `NtQuerySystemInformation()`:

```
PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION pspi = NULL;
ULONG info_length = 0;
NTSTATUS result = NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessInformation, NULL , 0, &info_length);
pspi = (PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION ) HeapAlloc ( .. , info_length , ..);
result = NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessInformation, pspi , info_length, &info_length);
if ( result != NT_SUCESS ) return ;
while (..)
{
  ...

  cout << pspi.ImageName.buffer ; 

  ...
}
```

this [pseudo] code print all the process running on the machine ***EXCEPT*** the calling process. 
I have no idea what can cause this behavior.

Comment: Show how you are iterating through the returned data, the `SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION` structs are not packed right next to each other. Also, you technically have a race condition if a process is started after your first call to `NtQuerySystemInformation` then your second call won't have enough space. Typically you add some additional space to allow for extra data.

Comment: What does this function offer that the Win32 functions do not?

Comment: @joshpoley you are absolutely right. I actually allocate 25% more vm in my code. moreover, I did have a mistake in the iteration process- I was iterating till `pspi.NextEntryOffset == 0` without including the last entity which was normally my process, as it was the last one to be stated.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan as for listing processes, it's the only way for getting all of them at once (one call), instead of using the enumeration function that forces you to also call `OpenProcess()` and `GetMoudleFileName()`. other then that, check http://www.exploit-monday.com/2013/06/undocumented-ntquerysysteminformation.html to see many more information classes that are available.

Comment: `EnumProcesses` gives you them all

Comment: true, but you have 2 more calls per process for getting all the *names*.